# Jquery hover for <a> element does not run?

Tags: jquery, html

Jquery hover for `<a>` element does not run?

I want to show button when hovering on image. I use Jquery hover to do that, but it doesn't succeed. I need your help for this. Here is my demo : http://jsfiddle.net/happi/t5u28/

Thanks for your help

Comment: `<a>` inside `<a>`? http://jsfiddle.net/rX5Gm/2/ --- have you tried to get it running BEFORE dealing with javascript? Seriously, if you cannot get "complex" things working - start from the scratch and change step by step

Comment: Also, your button is classed `the-button` yet your jQuery is looking for `.the-buttons`

Comment: To summarise, consider changing your outer `a` into `div`. http://jsfiddle.net/happi/t5u28/

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the DOM in the fiddle example you will see that the inner `<a>` tag is moved outside of the outer tag so that they are siblings. That is why you are unable to call `.find()` since it is not a descendant of the outer `<a>`

```
jQuery(function() {    
    jQuery(".the-button").hide();
    jQuery('a.show-image').hover(function() {
         jQuery('.the-button').fadeIn(1500);
    }, function() {
        jQuery('.the-button').fadeOut(1500); 
    });
});
```

Works because it is not trying to search the hovered `<a>` tags children but rather any `.the-button` elements in the document. You should come up with a better HTML structure.

Comment: so, have no solution for this? If i use <div>, it runs ok.

Comment: thats because `<a>` has the following constraint `The interactive element a must not appear as a descendant of the a element. ` from the w3 specifications

Comment: Yes. An anchor inside an anchor doesn't make sense because the anchor is hyperlinking whatever content is inside of it. So the enclosed anchor should not work if compliant to standards.

Answer (score 1):

as in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/happi/t5u28/) code change js in

```
jQuery(function() {    
    jQuery(".the-button").hide();
    jQuery('a.show-image').hover(function() {
        jQuery('.the-button').fadeIn(1500);
    }, function() {
        jQuery('.the-button').fadeOut(1500); 
    });
});
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/t5u28/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your requirements properly, this should do the trick.

```
<!-- Move second anchor outside the first one and let CSS handle the overlay effect -->
<a href="#" class="show-image">
    <img src="http://www.uniqlo.com/us/tiles/images/20130814/520bee8eae8a1.jpg" />   
</a>

<a href="#" class="the-button">Button here</a>
```

---

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".the-button").hide();


    $('a.show-image').mouseenter(function() {
      //  alert("hover");
         $('.the-button').fadeIn(1500);
    });

    $('a.show-image').mouseleave(function() {
      //  alert("hover");
         $('.the-button').fadeOut(1500);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jamespoulson/FPuSW/

P.S: The code can be condensed using a fadeToggle: http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have another `<a>` inside an anchor. I would suggest you to wrap you image in a `div`

```
jQuery(function() {    
    jQuery(".the-button").hide();
    jQuery('.show-image').hover(function() {
         jQuery(this).find('.the-button').fadeIn(1500);
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.the-button').fadeOut(1500); 
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rX5Gm/7/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".the-button").hide();
    $('a.show-image').hover(function() {
       $('.the-button').fadeIn(1500);
    },function()
    {
       $('.the-button').fadeOut(1500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Never make things complex when they can be done simply,
Just change

```
jQuery(this).find('.the-button').fadeIn(1500);
```

With

```
$('.the-button').fadeIn(1500);
```

Complete working code.

```
$(function() {    
    $(".the-button").hide();
    $('a.show-image').hover(function() {
         $('.the-button').fadeIn(1500);
    }, function() {
        $('.the-button').fadeOut(1500); 
    });
});
```

The working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t5u28/3/)

Comment: Assume if there are multiple buttons with class like `the-button` your code will fadeIn and fadeOut all of them. Sometime code has to be complex to meet the requirements. Perhaps!

Comment: only if you have the requirements @KhawerZeshan :)